# Runtime.getRuntime().exec() issue

Tags: java, process, exec, gdal

I'm trying to run another programm from Java code:

```
String[] command = {"gdal_polygonize.py", "/home/user/myoldfiles/proceeded.tiff", "-mask", "/home/user/myoldfiles/biomass_02.08.14.tif", "-f", "'ESRI Shapefile'", "/home/user/myoldfiles/proceeded.shp", "DN"};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

I have no file proceeded.shp created in /home/user/myoldfiles/
The command output obtained with BufferedReader looks like:

```
Creating output /home/user/myoldfiles/proceeded.shp of format 'ESRI Shapefile'.
```

When I run next command in terminal(Ubuntu)

```
 gdal_polygonize.py '/home/user/myoldfiles/proceeded.tiff' -mask '/home/user/myoldfiles/biomass_02.08.14.tif' -f 'ESRI Shapefile' '/home/user/myoldfiles/proceeded.shp'
```

It prints

```
Creating output /home/user/myoldfiles/proceeded.shp of format ESRI Shapefile.
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

And successfully creates proceeded.shp file. What am I doing wrong in Java code?

Comment: Try to provide the full path to: `gdal_polygonize.py`

Comment: The 'gdal_polygonize.py' is the command like "ls" or "cd"

Comment: It should give you an error of what is going wrong , for example `cannot find file gdal_polygonize.py` or something like that ... did you get any kind of error ? if so please edit

Comment: No errors, this confuses me. Only the messages that I posted =(

Comment: Are you waiting for the process to finish ?

Comment: Yes, I use p.waitFor(), that as I detected just now returns code "1"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for the help! I found solution [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69138/polygonize-py-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-createdatasou). The problem was in single quotes in 'ESRI Shapefile', I just deleted them and all works fine now!